# Why these queries returns different results?

Tags: sql-server, join, where-clause

Both of these sql server queries should return the same count result, but returns different - 8219 and 7876.
Left join should return all rows from left table (8219).
What could be the reason of such result (7876)?

```
select count(*)
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t2.[date]='20191001'
-- returns 7876

select count(*)
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
-- returns 8219 

select count(*)
from t2
where [date]<>'20191001' or [date] is null
-- returns 0
```

Comment: These are very different queries.  Why would you expect the result sets to be similar?

Comment: `where t2.[date]='20191001'`

Comment: "Both of these sql server queries should return the same count result" No, they shouldn't. As Gordon wrote in his answer, the fact that your first query use a column from t2 in the `where` clause is effectively changing it from a left join to an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query has a `LEFT JOIN`, but the `WHERE` clause is turning it into an inner join, because it filters out all `NULL` values.

The correct solution is to move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
select count(*)
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t2.[date] = '20191001';
```

Comment: Thanks!
So, if `outer` query with `where` clause turning it into `inner join` and in fact it is not `outer join` anymore, I would expect error pointing me to rewrite query ant not turning me back wrong results.
Is this "feature" documented?

Comment: @user10313400 . . . It is the definition of `OUTER JOIN`.